# sql query to subtract columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table which looks like this :

```
  Item  Month    Year    Sales
Name1      1     2013     333
Name2      2     2013     454
Name3      1     2013     434
```

I need to write a stored procedure which looks like this :

```
Item   Sales_On_Month(1)   Sales_On_Month(2)   Sales_On_Month(2)-Sales_On_Month(1)  Sales_On_Month(3) Sales_On_Month(3)-Sales_On_Month(2)
Name1           333                334                              1                        335             1
Name2           454                454                              0                        654             200
```

I tried the following query : 
I see a lot of nulls in the middle.If you could let me know the modifications to the query or another approach
it would be great :

```
select  (case when [MONTH] = 1 then Sales  END) AS Sales_On_Month(1),
 (case when [MONTH] = 2 then Sales  END) AS Sales_On_Month(2),
 (case when [MONTH] = 2 then Sales  END) - (case when [MONTH] = 1 then Sales  END) AS  Sales_On_Month(2)-Sales_On_Month(1) ...............
from ABC;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an aggregate, `SUM()`, MAX()`, whatever, and`GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT Item
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN [MONTH] = 1 THEN Sales END) AS Sales_1
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN  [MONTH] = 2 THEN Sales END) AS Sales_2
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN  [MONTH] = 2 THEN Sales END) - SUM(CASE WHEN [MONTH] = 1 THEN Sales END) AS  Sales_On_Month(2)-Sales_On_Month(1)
FROM ABC
GROUP BY Item
```

Comment: you've missed some parentheses to close the `sum()`s